# Solve the recursion given by $f(n) = 2f(n-1) + \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$ using generating functions.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, power-series, generating-functions, recursion

Assume that $f(0) = 0, f(1) = -1$.

$g(x)$ is $f(n)$'s generating function, I got to the expression:

$ g(x) = \frac{e^{-x}-1}{1-2x} $

But am now stuck, since I can't find a power series for the function in simple terms. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have $e^{-x}$ in your formula, not $e^x$.

Now you have $g(x) = (e^{-x}-1) \cdot \frac{1}{1-2x}$. Can you find power series for those both separately? Do you know how to multiply power series?

Comment: The exponent was just a spelling mistake which I now fixed. I do know how to multiply power series, but then I get a sum as the solution, which doesn't feel simplified enough. Is that usually considered a solution to a recursion?

Comment: Sometimes there may be a way to simplify the sum, but sometimes not.

Comment: In any case, you should still be able to say what happens to $f(n)$ asymptotically, which may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution might be expand the recursion equation here.

$$f(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} 2^{n-i} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} = 2^n\sum_{i = 1}^{n} 2^{-i} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$